# The fate of Poincaré recurrence with the Big Rip

Tags: cosmology, statistical-mechanics, universe, cosmological-constant, poincare-recurrence

Recently, there has been a lot of talk in the media about the "Big Rip". It most certainly resulted from the paper by Marcelo M. Disconzi and Thomas W. Kephart where they have figured out a mathematical system that allows the state parameter of the vacuum energy to drop below -1. Obviously this means the big rip is a possibility (perhaps a certainty?) and they have calculated the time frame to be 22 billion years. My question is what happens to the Poincaré recurrence theorem in a big rip universe? Is it still a possibility? And if yes then does the big rip lead us back to the classic Boltzmann brain situation?

Comment: The Poincare recurrence theorem doesn't have much meaning in classical mechanics, either, and it gets completely eliminated by quantum mechanics. For one thing it requires a constant phase space and for perfect recurrence that space would have to be both finite dimensional and discrete (classical mechanics doesn't provide that). In quantum mechanics the outcome of a future measurement is uncertain, even if the phase space is countable and has a discrete spectrum... which means that the future trajectory has a much larger number of choices than the past.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand how the existence of a set of states impacts Poincare recurrence. Maybe you could explain a bit. Also, have a look here http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94122/

Comment: Poincare recurrence depends on the topology of the phase space. It does, for instance, not occur at all in an open phase spaces, i.e. it wouldn't happen in the 19th century version of an infinite classical universe. Imagine a ball on a hill surrounded by an infinite flat plane. The ball rolls down the hill... and keeps rolling forever. No recurrence is possible in this trivial mechanical example.

Comment: That I agree with. I understand that it requires constant phase space and is at odds with classical mechanics. But I don't understand the quantum mechanics issue with it. Anyway why would we even consider classical mechanics here?

Comment: The Poincare recurrence theorem is a classical result. Quantum mechanics, on the other hand, clearly states that one can't predict the future outcome of measurements, so even if the entire universe could recreate the physicist and his measurement device, the next measurement would be just as much a coin toss as the one in the universe before. Nature does not know any more than the observer what the next macroscopic state will be. This leaves every possible future (within conservation laws, if they happen to be exact) completely open, even to nature. To me that's not recurrence.

Comment: I think you may have this a little wrong. See, the point is that Poincare recurrence is in the time frame of 10^120 billion years. So yes while uncertainty is inherent in Quantum Mechanics, given long enough time all sets of results will occur multiple times. It is precisely this uncertainty (quantum fluctuations) that make Poincare recurrence a possibility. I again refer you the question I linked earlier. The existence of the cosmic horizon means  that de Sitter space has a finite entropy.

Comment: Uncertainty doesn't go away magically just because you wait long enough. de Sitter space is a figment of human imagination and even if you take it seriously in an expanding universe you are sitting in an open system that keeps losing energy and matter constantly.  A photon heading for the event horizon is the analog of a ball rolling into infinity, you never get it back, not even if you keep running after it as fast as you can.

Comment: As per the holographic principle all information inside a black hole is encoded on it's horizon. So that information is never lost. I don't think this is even up for discussion any more. The fact that information is never lost has been proven beyond doubt by Susskind, Gerard t'hooft et all. And yes, de Sitter space is a figment of human imagination just the same way as say Minkowski space (in fact, de Sitter space isanalog in Minkowski space, of a sphere in Euclidean space), I don't think they are less relevant because of that.

Comment: The holographic principle is, at best, speculative. Even then the cosmological solution is not equivalent to a black hole... Can I be very honest with you? You seem to have your mind made up about what nature should look like and you aren't looking anymore at what nature actually does look like. A little less Susskind and a little more lab experience might cure that. See you in the lab!

Comment: Apologies, but this question was based on a very theoretical paper that provides a mathematical system for the state parameter of the vacuum energy to drop below -1. I don't believe my question is any more speculative than the paper itself, which proposes a date for the big-rip based on relativistic fluid dynamics. I have a lot of respect for experimental physics but that is not what this question is about. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: Every question in physics is experimental/observational. If somebody comes to me with a hypothesis about a big rip in 22 billion years, then I want to know how to test that hypothesis experimentally. If they can't tell me that, the paper goes into the wastebasket by default. So what kind of observational evidence is there for this result? What kind of experimental/observational data do we have for recurrence?

Comment: I am sorry @CuriousOne but I am not prepared for a political or philosophical debate here. As I said, that is not what this question is about. I am not discounting your point of view but honestly, this discussion is quite a distraction.

Comment: The definition of science and the requirements for hypotheses having to be testable is not a philosophical debate. It's simply something that you have to abide by if you are asking a scientific question. I am not putting undue burden on these kinds of suggestions, I am merely asking for the norm of scientific inquiry. You know as well as I do that recurrence even as proposed in its original form is a null-set. That's OK. It allows us to ask what we need to make it more than that. Discretization of the phase space is it, and that should be testable, right?

Comment: On discrete phase space, I am sure you have heard of the famous Wigner function. It's too difficult to elaborate on this in this small comment space. I refer you to 1) This excellent question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142746/what-is-discrete-phase-space and for more technical details 2) http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401155  and 3) http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6004

Comment: So now you have given me three citations, none of which addresses the EXPERIMENTAL question if nature has a discrete phase space or not. Where does that leave me except in an ever increasing position of doubt that assumes that you don't know the difference between theory and experiment?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no experimental proof for the existence of discrete space. There was no experimental proof for the general theory of relativity for a long time also. Meanwhile here is a discussion on potential experiments etc https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/are-there-evidences-of-a-discrete-space-time.306445/

Comment: I know all those things. Why do you think I am saying that there is no experimental confirmation, so far, not even for Planck scale physics (which wouldn't even be anywhere close to what you are suggesting)? Fermi is close to my heart, by the way. ;-)

Comment: By the way, if you are interested in how unstable theory is with regards to Big Rip singularities, take a look at "Phantom cosmology without Big Rip singularity", Artyom V. Astashenoka, Shinʼichi Nojirib, c, , , Sergei D. Odintsovb, d, e, Artyom V. Yurova. It really doesn't take much to eliminate this instability and the fits are (not surprisingly) as good as any. That's the problem with flying by theory alone: without observational data it's powerless.

Comment: I think the recent hype about the Big Rip is based partly on the evidence I've mentioned in my answer, and (most recently) by the 2020 appearance of a very entertaining pop.-sci. book (given the dismal but "hits-the-spot" title "Until the End of Time"), by Columbia University's Brian Greene, whose indexed references to Poincaré recurrence happened to catch Susskind on the upbeat side of his feelings about its veracity, which have varied.

Comment: The Big Rip would seem very inimical to Poincare recurrence, but (what with hindsight being better than foresight, etc.) analysis of data provided by the James Webb Space Telescope shows little evidence for the activity (accelerating expansion) which woulld characterize a Rip, and, in fact, shows little evidence for spatial expansion at all, as discussed at https://www.ldolphin.org/nobigbang.html  .

Comment: One caveat:  The aforementioned reference does seem consistent with the purely spatial expansion (an expansion that "is not a force or drag carrying astronomical objects with it") described by Lineweaver & Davis in their papers on "expanding confusion".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the commentary posted by the OP and by Curious One, wouldn't observational data include any decrease in that proportion of space where every line of sight ends at a star? We've seen evidence for that decrease, in more than 90 formerly binary stars whose onetime partner has disappeared, through the fact that each of the surviving partners still follows the elliptical orbit it once shared with that partner.

Another part of the process (that acceleration of spatial expansion which was first discovered by each of two rival teams of researchers in the late 1990's) would plainly be consistent with the start of a Big Rip.  The disintegration that precedes recurrence is a necessary prelude to the recurrence itself, and the processes involved may have evidently begun, even within our observable region.

The cosmological model most consistent with these processes may be the "Cosmology with torsion" formulated, since 2010, by Nikodem Poplawski, using 1929's Einstein-Cartan Theory rather than 1915's General Relativity:  In ECT, a tiny spatial extent (some orders of magnitude greater than the Planck length) was assigned to fermions, previously considered to be point-like.  ECT was formulated by Einstein in collaboration with the mathematician Cartan,  after the discovery (in the mid-1920's) of particulate spin.   Poplawski's model provides a version of cosmic inflation, but does not require a field of  "inflaton" particles, that do remain entirely hypothetical.

In the torsion-based model, any large rotating star that's collapsing under its own weight (after expenditure of its nuclear fuel has left it with radiation pressure insufficient to prevent its collapse) begins the formation of a black hole:  In a single bounce or a series of smaller bounces, fermions newly-materialized by separation from  their partners in virtual pairs, through tidal effects in the intense gravitational field within the collapsing stellar volume, are spun outward through contact with the stellar fermions (initially much larger) within that volume, to form a new "local universe" that's causally separated (like all black holes) from the larger multiverse within which all of this activity is occurring.  The shape of each such new LU has been analogized by Poplawski to "the skin of a basketball", and clearly fits the description of a closed (but local) universe, within a larger inflationary multiverse.

The causal separation is essential for  Poincaré recurrence, formulated by  Poincaré in 1890 and proven mathematically correct by Cathéodory in 1919, which provides for nearly-identical arrangements of particles to appear, at extremely long intervals of time, within any closed  volume.  That separation consequently provides the simplest explanation for the fact that, although the multiverse may be isotropic, as well as incomparably larger than our observable region, every line of sight from the earth does not end at a star.  As each local universe in Poplawski's model inherits its "arrow of time" from its parent, the model has the "falsifiable" nature required of scientific theories, and there has been some data (by Cai and by Lior Shamir), showing a prevalent direction of motion, which tends to support it:  However, given the size (for us) of our Observable Region, and the strong possibility that there are many sequences of black holes on sequentially- decreasing spatio-temporal scales, definitive proof may remain unlikely for a while.

Although Poplawski's model was found to be consistent with the CMB data in a preprint by Desai titled "Non-parametric reconstruction of an inflaton potential" that (like preprints of the many papers, written by Poplawski between 2010 and 2021, detailing his model) can be seen freely on Cornell University's Arxiv website, it remains unpopular in some parts of the world, perhaps partly because of ECT's exceptionally complex notation, but also because his cosmological model is one of several that are potentially eternal to the past as well as to the future, and are, consequently, unpopular with creationistic religions that remain politically and economically influential in some state and private university systems within the United States, as well as in some other regions.

The paper by Visconzi et al that the OP has cited (titled "A new approach to cosmological bulk viscosity"), posits (within its first few paragraphs) a future singularity, but Poplawski's past- and future-eternal model "avoids" (to use the terminology employed by its author) any singularity. At least by my reading of the verbiage in Poplawski's 2010 model, in conjunction with some resemblances of it to Roger Penrose's "Conformal cyclic cosmology" (also formulated in 2010, & also past- and future-eternal, but differing from it in a dependence on singularities), the difference between ECT and GR may explain this.  (Poplawski's 2010 paper was subtitled "An alternative to cosmic inflation", but has generally been considered to present a variant of inflation, which can most simply be described as asymptotically-exponential spatial expansion.)

Comment: I think that there may be some misapprehension that the recurrence theorem imposes some sort of constraint on the duration of modeled cosmologies.  In fact, however, as pointed out in the currently-unchallenged Wikipedia description of it, for a given phase in a volume, the recurrence is not necessarily a periodic recurrence:  The second recurrence time does not need to be double the first recurrence time.

Comment: To me, recurrence seems to be the most plausible aspect of physics, whose purpose is generally the prediction of phenomena:  It's difficult to picture phenomena appearing that would not be at least similar to phenomena which would've arisen earlier, or, at least, to up- or down-scaled versions of them.

Comment: In Greene's book (mentioned in a comment on the OP's question), Poincare recurrence is confounded with Boltzmann Brains, a phenomenon anti-social enough that an earlier completion of the Rip is contemplated as a pleasant alternative, even if it would be as permanent as its correspondence to a (universal, not local) Big Bang would symmetrically imply: However, I myself find that such dismal alternatives are less plausible than the repetitions, on sequentially decreasing scales, that seem to characterize Poplawski's model: Why have scale invariance in relativistic theory, if it's not utilized?

Comment: What I'm getting at, in my answer, is that a model with a future singularity of consequential size & duration may not be compatible with Poincare's recurrence, although a past- and future-eternal model (of which there are several, including Aguirre & Gratton's "Steady-state eternal inflation", in addition to the others that I've mentioned in my comments and answer) would be, if the universe or Universe (i.e., "local universe") concerned would be closed. (I believe Aguirre & JM Deutsch have yet another fully-eternal model, called "State-to-state cosmology", that's currently a work in progress.)

Comment: I'm surprised by Greene's assumption, on p.382-384 in the book I've cited (which deals with religion as well as with science), that Poincare's theorem would be most problematic in recurrences centered around the violent 1890-2021 period (during which the basis for Poplawski's model was developed), rather than that period of naturalistic, physical formation of an observable region with which Poincare was generally concerned. As near as I can guess, Greene's wanting to banish complacency during a critical environmental deterioration, against which real sanctions have yet to be proposed.

Comment: So, whether recurrence should be pushed or pulled (into or from) the educational curriculum should probably depend on the audience addressed, with recurrence on cosmological scales competing with the ever-popular (but unfortunately brief) genealogical version of watered-down self-perpetuation....